# Why is Jawbone UP step data deleted from Health app after midnight?

Tags: iphone, health.app, health-kit

How do I get the iOS Health app to retain the previous days' worth of step data?

The iOS Health app only shows the current day's steps.

My [UP3](https://jawbone.com/store/buy/up3) is set up to be the primary data source for updating the Steps tracker in the Health app.  During the day, when I check the Health app, the steps recorded match the steps registered in the UP app.

However, when I wake up in the morning, the previous day's steps are gone from the Health app and when I click on "Show All Data" it only show's the present day's data - there is nothing from any previous days. Interestingly, the Health app records and retains all previous days' worth of Sleep Analysis data synced from UP app.

### Hardware and Software

- iPhone 6 running iOS 9.2 (up to date)
- [Jawbone UP3](https://jawbone.com/store/buy/up3) with firmware: 1.2.14 (up to date)
- [UP by Jawbone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/up-by-jawbone-track-health/id916240764?mt=8) version 4.12.1 (up to date)

Comment: I have the same issue with my UP3. But on some days the data is there. I have not figured out jet how to prevent deleting the data. It would be nice to have the correct stepcount in health app.

Comment: Please can you contact [Jawbone support](https://help.jawbone.com/contact). This sounds like a software bug and something they should be made aware of.